# RStudio local job: "source" multiple scripts using "sapply" will return nothing

Tags: r, rstudio, local, sapply

I have three scripts in the same directory: main.R, func1.R, func2.R. The codes are

main.R:

```
rm(list = ls())
x <- 0
filelist <- c("func2.R", "func1.R")
print(ls())
sapply(filelist, source)
print(ls())
```

func1.R:

```
x1 <- 1
```

func2.R:

```
x2 <- 2
```

If I run main.R in RStudio, the output will be

```
[1] "filelist" "x"       
[1] "filelist" "x"        "x1"       "x2"
```

This means the results of func1.R and func2.R are exported into the global environment. However, if I submit main.R as a local job in RStudio, the output will be

```
[1] "filelist" "x"       
[1] "filelist" "x"
```

I know I can solve this by using loop to `source` each script separately. I'm simply curious the reason why the `sapply` function behaves differently in console and local job, and how to make it work if I insist using `sapply` to `source` all scripts together? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a misunderstanding of what is meant by **local job**. The feature run local job is quite a new feature from RStudio and lets the user start a job and run it local somewhere so that it is **not** inferring with the users own session. The main Idee here is that if you have some computationally heavy job you start this on some other maschine and then collect the results when they are done. If you want the scripts to run in your own session you should use the classic `source` command

Comment: Thanks for your answering, but I'm still a little confused. Do you mean `source` function cannot be used in a script submitted in local job? I have a main script and the time of running main script is more than 24 hours, so I tried to use local job. However, all the functions used in main script are defined in several other R scripts, that's why I need to use `source` function in the main script. Can't I use local job unless I put all code in a single script file? Thanks.